# Discontinuous function proof using $\epsilon - \delta$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

$f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$

Showing $f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc} 3x,&x\in\Bbb Q\\-3x,&x\in \Bbb I\end{array}\right.$

---

I want to show that $f(x)$ is discontinuous for all $x\ne0$ using $\epsilon - \delta$

---

So I want to show:

$$\exists \epsilon \gt 0 , \forall \delta \gt 0| |x-l|\lt \delta, |f(x)-f(l)|\gt \epsilon$$

Now I believe I should pin this to four cases: 1)$x,l\in \Bbb Q$,$\quad$2)$x\in \Bbb Q,l\in\Bbb I$,$\quad$3)$l\in \Bbb Q,x\in \Bbb I$,$\quad$4)$x,l\in \Bbb I$

So case $1)$:

$$|x-l|\lt \delta, |2x-2l|\gt \epsilon$$
$$|x-l|\lt\delta,2|x-l|\gt\epsilon$$
$$\implies 3\delta \gt |xl| \gt \epsilon$$

---

Now I have no idea what to do for case 1 and I haven't attempted other cases yet since I assume a similar problem will occur.

I put my delta after my epsilon, so I can't choose an epsilon relying on my delta, hence I am confused.

Comment: $f$ is **bi-continuous** - its 2 functions in 1. if you define $f$ on $\mathbb{Q}$ as per se, with on $\mathbb{I}$ as the closest rational, it is cont.

Comment: @Jon $\Bbb I$ is the set of irrationalsd

Comment: yeah i know - innit great! $\mathbb{I}=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: $\mathbb{I}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are both cont., so so is $\mathbb{Q}$, otherwise we have union of discontinuous set is cont.

Answer (score 0):

you need more quantifiers and then it may be clearer.

$$
 \forall x \neq 0, \; \exists \epsilon > 0 , \forall \delta \gt 0,  \exists l, \;\text{ such that }  |x-l|\lt \delta, \text{ and }|f(x)-f(l)|\gt \epsilon
$$

in particular you don't need to consider cases 1 and 4 since existence of some $l$ is the question not for all $l.$